# Bootstrap button group not activable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to avoid the active class in this button group:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="level1" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" />
        <span class="fa fa-square fa-square-1"></span>
    </label>
    <label id="level2" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" />
        <span class="fa fa-square fa-square-1"></span>
    </label>
    <label id="level3" class="btn btn-xs btn-default">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" />
        <span class="fa fa-square fa-square-1"></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

I've tryied with:

```
$(document).on("click", '#level1, #level2, #level3', function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

but no way. What I'm looking for is to have a button group which can be clicked but no one of the buttons will mantein the active class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can not understand propely ? what is exactly you want to do ?, click on any radio button you want to remove active class ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use radio buttons.

From http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-single (modified to your example):

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <button id="level1" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-square fa-square-1"></span>
  </button>
  <button id="level2" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-square fa-square-1"></span>
  </button>
  <button id="level3" type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-square fa-square-1"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```